# Which Platform to choose for a Facebook App based on Qt (Symbian) using Graph api v2?

Tags: facebook, qt, facebook-graph-api

I'm making my first Facebook App with Qt on Symbian. I've created it on Facebook Developer, but to get it through a permission review (it only posts on the users timeline) I need to add a Platform, but I don't know which one too choose since the OS or Qt are not listed there, I have auth enabled in the settings too.

[image]

Does anyone know which one I need to choose to get the App approved and working?

Comment: How do the user login?

Comment: They would use OAuth to login, Client OAuth Login is enabled from the Apps Settings, still asks for a Platform to be added though.


It does authorize me since I'm the App admin, but also won't update my status, says FacebookConnection::requestFailed - Reason: "Host  not found" when I send the message through

It's based on this: https://github.com/nokia-developer/social-connect-qml-plugin

Comment: Ok for some reason it just let me post from it, App details from Facebook say it is misconfigured, don't know if thats because it's in development mode or not